# variant of scientific notation on pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath

I use scientific notation on pgf to display numbers.
My present code as  follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
/pgf/number format/.cd,
sci,
sci generic={mantissa sep=\times, exponent={10^{#1}}}, 
sci zerofill,
precision=1
}
\pgfmathprintnumber{350}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{4.568}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.1}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.012}\hspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

These results are follows:

```
3.5×10^2    1.2×10^1    4.6×10^0    1.0×10^−1    1.2×10^-2
```

However, I don't want to only display 10^(-1), 10^0 and 10^1.
I want to display as follows:

```
3.5×10^2    12    4.6   0.10    1.2×10^-2
```

How should I improve my code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I changed the title of your question, as you do not want scientific notation, but some variant of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `std` key:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgf}

    \begin{document}


    \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    sci,
    std={-1:1},
    sci generic={%
     mantissa sep=
      {
       \times 
      },
      exponent={
       10^{#1}%
      },
    },
    sci zerofill,
    precision=1
    }

    \pgfmathprintnumber{350}\hspace{1em}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{12}\hspace{1em}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{4.568}\hspace{1em}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{0.1}\hspace{1em}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{0.012}\hspace{1em}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I can solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,precision=2}
\pgfmathprintnumber{350}\hspace{1em}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,std,precision=1}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{4.568}\hspace{1em}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,std,precision=2}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.1}\hspace{1em}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,std,precision=1}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.012}\hspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I can solve my problem!